# Create a sequence from big power numbers

Tags: r, vector, sequence, gmp

I'm trying to create a sequence of integers from big numbers and couldn't find a way to suceed. Is there a way to do this ?

I tried :

`(2^128):(2^128+3000)` which returns: `[1] 3.402824e+38`

So I tried to use the `gmp` library :

```
library(gmp)
as.bigz(2^128):as.bigz(2^128+3000)
```

and got

> ```
> messages: 1: In as.bigz(2^128):as.bigz(2^128 + 3000) :   numerical
> expression has 32 elements: only the first used 2: In
> as.bigz(2^128):as.bigz(2^128 + 3000) :   numerical expression has 32
> elements: only the first used
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your sequence to your "big number":

```
library(gmp)
as.bigz(2^128) + 0:3000
```

```
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 3001:
[1] 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 340282366920938463463374607431768211457 
[3] 340282366920938463463374607431768211458 340282366920938463463374607431768211459
[5] 340282366920938463463374607431768211460 340282366920938463463374607431768211461
# ...
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `seq`

```
library(gmp)
seq(as.bigz(2^128), length.out = 3001)
```